# i need to calculate age using and ID number(without the century of birth being given) and the calendar class in java, any suggestions?

Tags: java, date

I am doing a project in which i need to work out age using a birth date supplied using an ID number (which does not give whether or not the person was born in 20th or 21st century)and then using the calendar class I need to calculate the person's age for comparison to the minimum age requirements of the program they are trying to join. how would i go about teaching the program to select '19' or '20' to put before the decade and year? i have tried to ask the user to input their age and gender in separate fields but have found this to be inefficient as i thereafter need to combine all of the user's information to give their file a unique identifier whereas the ID number is already a unique identifier that gives both age and gender but not the century in which they were born.

Comment: So... What data *do* you have about the person?  Anything resembling a date of birth?  Can the user not input their date of birth when registering?

Comment: they supply their name, surname, email, phone number and an ID number- for example : 9509155113079 - which I need to use to calculate their date of birth. The first six digits represent their age, '95 means they were born in '95 and the 09 is the month and 15 the day. But the 95 is not indicative on whether it is 2095 or 1995 which is something that the computer needs to decide  but unfortunately would trip up on if it were from 00 to (the current year) because it could be from the 20th or 21st century.

Comment: In that case you'd have to either include the date of birth in the fields being entered or make an assumption about the 2-digit year (such as assuming anything > the current 2-digit year is the previous century, else the current century) and hope every user meets that assumption.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't already have that information, there's no way to "teach" the program... The best you could do with what you have is *assume* that no users will be over 100 years old (or some similar hack), and say that birth years ending in 00-14 were born in the 21st century, and birth years ending in 15-99 were born in the 20th century.

The **better** solution is just to do the extra work on the "inefficient" separate fields solution and avoid the hack I described above. In addition to ignoring the fact that there are 100+-year-olds out there, it's not a lasting or robust solution. More work on your part is better to create more robust and functional code.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful! i will try the hack way first to try keep the ID number as my unique identifier but if I run aground with it i will have to switch back to DOB as a manual input.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String IDNO = "9509155193194"; //made up this ID number
    Calendar cal;
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    String y1,y2,y3,y4,m1,m2,d1,d2,y3c,y4c,y3n4,y3n4c;
    y1 = "0";
    y2 = "0";
    y3 = temp.valueOf(temp.charAt(0));
    y4 = temp.valueOf(temp.charAt(1));
    m1 = temp.valueOf(temp.charAt(2));
    m2 = temp.valueOf(temp.charAt(3));
    d1 = temp.valueOf(temp.charAt(4));
    d2 = temp.valueOf(temp.charAt(5));
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyyMMdd");
    y3n4 = y3 + y4;
    Integer calcy3n4 = Integer.parseInt(y3n4);
    String curryear = df.format(cal.getTime()).toString();
    y3c = curryear.valueOf(curryear.charAt(2));
    y4c = curryear.valueOf(curryear.charAt(3));
    y3n4c = y3c + y4c;
    Integer calcy3n4c = Integer.parseInt(y3n4c);
    if (calcy3n4>calcy3n4c)
    {
        y1 = "1";
        y2 = "9";
    }
    if (calcy3n4 >= 0 && calcy3n4 <= calcy3n4c)
    {
        y1 = "2";
        y2 = "0";
    }
    String YOB = y1 + y2 + y3 + y4;
    String curyear = curryear.valueOf(curryear.charAt(0)) + curryear.valueOf(curryear.charAt(1)) + curryear.valueOf(curryear.charAt(2)) + curryear.valueOf(curryear.charAt(3));
    Integer Yob = Integer.parseInt(YOB);
    Integer cYear = Integer.parseInt(curyear);
    Integer yAge = cYear - Yob;
    String MOB = m1 + m2;
    String curmonth = curryear.valueOf(curryear.charAt(4)) + curryear.valueOf(curryear.charAt(5));
    Integer Mob = Integer.parseInt(MOB);
    Integer cMonth = Integer.parseInt(curmonth);
    String DayOB = d1 + d2;
    String curday = curryear.valueOf(curryear.charAt(6)) + curryear.valueOf(curryear.charAt(7));
    Integer Dayob = Integer.parseInt(DayOB);
    Integer cDay = Integer.parseInt(curday);
    if(cMonth < Mob)
    {
        yAge --;

    }
    else 
    {
        if (cMonth == Mob)
    {
        if(cDay < Dayob)
        {
           yAge --; 
        }
        else
        {

        }
    } 
    }
    System.out.println(yAge);
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, may not be the most efficient but it has worked, to teh day for added accuracy.